# Python BS4 not allowed to access the web page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

[image: Image for easy comprehension]

First i used html_doc=requests.get(x) to read the page but when i printed the soup, i got 403 Forbidden error.

In order to bypass this, i added a User Agent and used this code: html_doc=requests.get(x, headers=header)
However, this time, i got a 400 Bad Request error when i tried to print the soup.

Could some one guide me and help find a solution to this problem?

Edit - Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
from urllib import request
import requests
import lxml
from lxml import etree
from lxml import html
x='https://www.topstockresearch.com/INDIAN_STOCKS/COMPUTERS_SOFTWARE/Wipro_Ltd.html'
header = {'User Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0)'}
html_doc=requests.get(x, headers=header)  #With header
html_doc=requests.get(x) #Without Header
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

URL: x=https://www.topstockresearch.com/INDIAN_STOCKS/COMPUTERS_SOFTWARE/Wipro_Ltd.html

Thanks for reading!

EDIT2: Solved by using this code:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://www.topstockresearch.com/INDIAN_STOCKS/COMPUTERS_SOFTWARE/Wipro_Ltd.html', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

print(response.text)
```

PS: im just learning coding and this is not for any work related purposes. Just a personal project relating to the stock market.

Comment: Please don't post image of the code, post it as text so we can copy-paste it. Also, what is the URL?

Comment: If you are not going to share the value of `x` we will not be able to assist :-(

Comment: Did you try HTTP GET to https://www.topstockresearch.com/charts/csv/133/73D.csv?var=14 - it contains interesting data.

Comment: @balderman Thank you for your comment, by using the get function in the requests module, i was able to find a solution from another similar question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll need to use `User-Agent:`  not `User Agent:`. HTTP headers should not use spaces in their keys.